# inline asm compiled in XCode for Simulator but failed to compile for Device

Tags: c, assembly, arm, port, intel

I have been googling for quite a long time but still find no solution. I hope someone can help me on this.

I have three inline asm functions as below:

```
static __inline__ int Bsf(uint32_t Operand) {
  int eax;
  asm __volatile__ (
    "bsfl %0, %0" "\n\t"
    : "=a" (eax)
    : "0" (Operand)
  );
  return eax;
}

static __inline__ int Bsr(uint32_t Operand) {
  int eax;
  asm __volatile__ (
    "bsrl %0, %0" "\n\t"
    : "=a" (eax)
    : "0" (Operand)
  );
  return eax;
}

static __inline__ uint64_t TimeStampCounter(void) {
  uint32_t eax, edx;
  asm __volatile__ (
    "rdtsc" "\n\t"
    : "=a" (eax), "=d" (edx)
    :
  );
  return MAKE_LONG_LONG(eax, edx);
}
```

They all compiled successfully in XCode for Simulator, but failed when I switched to build for Device - 4.1 (for iPhone ). The message i got is "impossible constraint in asm". I believe the problem is the above assembly code does not work for ARM based cpu. Can someone shed some light on how to re-write the code so it compile for iPhone cpu? It can be either assembly or pure C code. Thanks in advance!

Leo

Comment: Just a guess but the assembly you posted is x86 and iOS devices are ARM based so you probably need to write the ARM assembly to do what you want.

Comment: @Dean. You are absolutely right, and that is actually my question. How do I re-write the code for ARM cpu? Do you have any idea? That'd be much appreciated if you could shed some light on re-writing it in either ARM assembly or pure C code.

Comment: @user538220 - you need to answer my question from two days ago - "What are you trying to do?"  The `rdtsc` instruction has no equivalent on ARM, so you need to explain to us the use cases for these routines and what you'd like their semantics to be.  The `Bsf()` and `Bsr()` functions are trivial to implement in C - `TimeStampCounter()` not so much (at least without more information about the system and the problems you're having).

Comment: @Carl. Sorry for not answering your question, but I thought I explained already. I wanted to translate those functions into code that can run on ARM cpu. It can be either ARM assembly or C. If you were asking what those functions are used for, I am not quite sure to be honest. I am just trying to migrate someone's code into iOS system. To the assembly experts, I guess the above functions explain themselves clearly, and very easy to be translated into C or ARM assembly? If you could please write a couple of line of the equivalent C code for the Bsf() and Bsr(), that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: @user538220 - the right solution is to figure out what these functions are used for and why the code you're porting needs them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the ARM `clz` instruction to replace `bsr`.  I don't know any good replacements for the other two.

Edit:  OP clarified some context.

You need to get the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/).  They contain a full instruction set reference which will help you out.  Even pseudocode for the `bsf`/`bsr` instructions is in there, and can be easily translated into their C equivalents:

```
int Bsf(uint32_t n) {
{
    int m;

    for (m = 0; m < 32; m++)
    {
        if (n & (1 << m))
            return m;
    }

    return 32;
}

int Bsr(uint32_t n) {
{
    int m;

    for (m = 31; m >= 0; m--)
    {
        if (n & (1 << m))
            return m;
    }

    return 32;
}
```

The `rdtsc` instruction reads the processor's time-stamp counter, which is a 64-bit value incremented every clock cycle:

> The processor monotonically increments the time-stamp counter MSR every clock cycle and resets it to 0 whenever the processor is reset.

You'll need to figure out why your program needs that information, and how best to translate it to your ARM case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will try with your code and let you know if it works. I guess it's time for me to learn a little assembly. :)

Comment: Yes, your code does work perfectly. Thanks. Now I gotta find a way to replace the "rdtsc".